Spectre attack via JavaScript why is TABLE1_BYTES = 2^25
I am reading the Spectre Paper [1] and don't understand why the bitwise AND is needed and why TABLE1_BYTES is 2^25.
1 if (index < simpleByteArray.length) {
2   index = simpleByteArray[index | 0];
3   index = (((index * TABLE1_STRIDE)|0) & (TABLE1_BYTES-1))|0;
4   localJunk ^= probeTable[index|0]|0;
5 }

We know from the paper that:
TABLE1 STRIDE = 4096 
TABLE1 BYTES = 2^25

As per my understanding, the stride is 4k such that the secret values will be in different cache-lines within the cache set. In paper it says:

The clflush instruction is not accessible from JavaScript, so cache
flushing was performed by reading a series of addresses at 4096-byte
intervals out of a large array. Because of the memory and cache
configuration on Intel processors, a series of ˜2000 such reads
(depend- ing on the processor’s cache size) were adequate evict out
the data from the processor’s caches for addresses having the same
value in address bits 11–6

I still dont get why the bitwise and is needed and why TABLE1_BYTES is so large.
[1]:

https://spectreattack.com/spectre.pdf


To make the index wrap around when it reaches the end of the table instead of doing an array index out of bounds. And the text explains the array size: it needs to be big enough to allow at least 2000 different locations
